# VLC Media Player - Extremely long delays before some DVDs play / show any menu

Tags: troubleshooting, dvd, vlc-media-player, media-player

With some DVDs there's a long delay before a movie begins.  No menus, nothing.
With a couple of movies it's an extremely long delay (For example Hollow Man finally shows a menu after about 7.5 minutes of a blank screen - then you get a working menu.  Windows Media Player begins Hollow Man immediately (but lack other functionality I need).

I tried changing the setting:
Input/Codecs, Access moduel, DVD with menus, Start directly in menu

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the dvdcss decryption taking place.   Since VLC didn't pay the (huge) Royalties, they don't get the set of keys to unlock a DVD immediately.  Of course, the dvdcss libraries reverse engineer those, but it takes a little while for some DVD's, each DVD is different.  The keys are cached, so if you play that DVD again later, it can be decrypted quickly, but the first time is going to be delayed by this processing.